# Websphere MQ Connection timed out

Tags: java, websphere, database-connection, ibm-mq, connection-timeout

I'm using WAS WebSphere and IBM MQ. My application must parse a message placed into a queue, then insert parsed data into database (DB2). It was working good until some large message was placed into the queue. Message was parsed successfully, but when the application started inserting to the database, Listener Port was stopped by the following error:

```
[10/25/15 23:57:44:022 GMT+06:00] 00000037 MDBListenerIm I   WMSG0042I: MDB    Listener ADAPTER.GBDRN.IN started successfully for JMSDestination  jms/ADAPTER.GBDRN.
IN
[10/25/15 23:59:44:044 GMT+06:00] 00000042 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0006W:   Transaction    00000150A0261DE500000001000066841D74FABA0FC48659721E8A1B6DB84C0E5C29909A00000150A0261DE500000001000066841D74FABA0FC48659721E8A1B6DB84C0E5C29909A00000001 has    timed out after 120 seconds.
[10/25/15 23:59:44:049 GMT+06:00] 00000042 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[MessageListenerThreadPool : 1,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was:
    java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceElement(Native Method)
    java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:591)
    java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(Throwable.java:582)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo.<init>(LocationInfo.java:139)
```

I've configured the maximum size of the WMQCommonServices thread pool in the application server, as shown [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21317935)

1- Click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere Application Servers > server name.

2- Under Additional Properties, click Thread pools> WMQCommonServices.

3- Update the value of the Maximum size field to the relevant value and click OK.

4- Click Save and restart the application server.

But I still facing the problem with listener port connection timeout

Comment: Have you considered increasing the timeout from `120` seconds to a larger value?

Comment: There're 180 seconds in Resources > JDBC Providers > JDBC_provider > Data Sources > data_source > Connection Pool.

Comment: The error says timeout after 120 seconds, so clearly it's not the same timeout.

Comment: You might need to consider a different application design. You can start with `Claim Check` patten. And I would separate application logic from message listener (i.e. MDB). Another option would be create EJB with new separate Transaction to save/process incoming message. Do not include propagate MDB transaction to the application logic or build own retry/recovery logic.

Comment: This is not related to connection timeout, but transaction timeout. You can increase that timeout via `Server > Container Services > Transaction service` and change `total transaction lifetime timeout` there. However you should really check what takes more than 2 min there, message parsing or database update and try to optimize it.

Comment: @Gas Thank you, it helped me!